# is there any way to combine multiple joins for same table? WP Meta Query for V 4.6

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, join

i am stuck in post meta filter its taking too much time to retrieve result at the end query execution time out.....

I am not looking for increasing time or anything i need to combine multiple join or any other solution for my this query

```
SELECT sql_calc_found_rows wp_posts.id 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.id = mt1.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.id = mt2.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_posts.id = mt3.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt4 ON ( wp_posts.id = mt4.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt5 ON ( wp_posts.id = mt5.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt6 ON ( wp_posts.id = mt6.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt7 ON ( wp_posts.id = mt7.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt8 ON ( wp_posts.id = mt8.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1
AND (
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wa_prod_Company' 
    AND (
        ( mt1.meta_key = 'wa_prod_Duration' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE '%%' ) 
        AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'wa_prod_Connection' AND mt2.meta_value > '0' ) 
        AND ( mt3.meta_key = 'wa_prod_BW' AND mt3.meta_value >= '0' ) 
        AND ( mt4.meta_key = 'wa_prod_HDD' AND Cast(mt4.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '0' ) 
        AND ( mt5.meta_key = 'wa_prod_Price' AND Cast(mt5.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '0' AND '2000' )
        AND ( mt6.meta_key = 'wa_prod_Availability' AND mt6.meta_value LIKE '%on%' ) 
        AND (
                ( mt7.meta_key = 'wa_prod_Type' AND mt7.meta_value LIKE '%Shared%' ) 
            OR  ( mt7.meta_key = 'wa_prod_Type' AND mt7.meta_value LIKE '%Semi Dedicated%' )
            OR  ( mt7.meta_key = 'wa_prod_Type' AND mt7.meta_value LIKE '%Dedicated%' ) 
            ) 
        AND (
                ( mt8.meta_key = 'wa_prod_Premium_Featurs' AND mt8.meta_value LIKE '%SSD%' )
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND (( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' )) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.id 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC limit 0, 10
```

i have try with just one join `INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id )` and remove others and mt1, mt2 replace with wp_postmeta but its not retrieving result.

i have several more filters but just after applying 8 filter query not retrieving anything because of SQL Server time out...

i have also tried [meta-query-terribly-slow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158898/meta-query-terribly-slow) but not work becuase it's not support WP V 4.6

Comment: Why do you have multiple `INNER JOIN` for the same table doing essentially the same thing? You just need the check the `postmeta` table when it's `post_id` is same as the `ID` in the `posts` table. Can you describe what you have in your `postmeta` table, and what it is that you are trying to achieve. This seems unnecessarily complicated...

Comment: @dingo_d wp meta query generating this and it's dynamically generated query by WP... [WP Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Comment: @PankajPawar for anyone else intention , i think maybe using meta_query_find_compatible_table_alias filter help to solve multiple join problem.

Answer (score 0):

1)Temporary solution for this query increase server execution time
For maximum execution time try:

set_time_limit(0);

Also try to optimize your query. And use sleep in between each interval of 50 or 100 slots.

2)minimum  use of like, use mt7.meta_key = 'wa_prod_Type' AND mt7.meta_value = 'Shared' if possible.

Comment: there is json in database where i have use "like". thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

wp_postmeta has inefficient indexes. Here is a discussion of such, plus recommended cures:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

You should also consider a `FULLTEXT` index to replace the tedious `LIKE '%...%'` conditions.